# How can I make a wedding toast in Spanish (1 sentence)?

Tags: weddings, spanish-language

¡Hola! I'm going to make a wedding speech for the groom next week in Spain. I will give the speech in English, but I'd like to end it with the Spanish quote (bride is Spanish). Any suggestion on the one sentence wedding toast in Spanish?

Thanks in advance :)

P.S. I've asked reddit for help, but I only got the uncensored ones (some quite funny though)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Spanish.SE

Comment: @JonathanReez true, but also about culture of a destination country and local habits. It may fit here also. He could be asking about saying hello, or how to behave in a particular situation.

Comment: I suggest ["¡Mi aerodeslizador está lleno de anguilas!"](http://www.omniglot.com/language/phrases/hovercraft.htm)

Comment: @nsn True. Although all I can read in this question is a purely linguistic need, rather than a cultural one. Casting the last close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here in Spain it would be very typical to end the toast saying: ¡Vivan los novios!, in a typical catholic wedding this sentence would also be employed when the newly married went out of the church and people started throwing rice at them and shouting this aloud.

It means (more or less, I don't know how to translate it exactly) that you're wishing them a long and happy life together.

Comment: translates roughly as 'long live the bride and groom'